# RadioButton not displaying

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

There're 2 RadioButtons in my application. They are both displayed in xml in AndroidStudio, but when I run the app on the phone, they disappear. It's not because of their positioning or some random function - for the sake of testing I placed another RadioButton and didn't do anything with it. When I ran the app, it didn't get displayed either. The only problem I see is something with styles, but they seem to be fine. I'll still post the codes:

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Male"
    android:id="@+id/maleBtn" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Female"
    android:id="@+id/femaleBtn"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/maleBtn"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="My.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: post your complete layout code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code, I believe the some where in your layout parent of your `RadioButton` is changing the visibility or Due to orientation of the parent you are not able to see the `RadioButton`

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Male" />


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Female" />
    </RadioGroup>
```